# CSS styles showing framed border on rendered PDF visual force page

Tags: visualforce, css

I'm not able to show just a solid border around visualforce data tables rendered on a pdf using the following visualforce tag and CSS. table shows as a framed style.

[image]

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="section2c" title="Expiring Contract Experience" showHeader="true" rendered="{!NOT(PriorYRcontractSectionList.size == 0)}" > 
         <apex:outputPanel id="out2c">
            <apex:actionstatus startText="loading...">
                <apex:facet name="stop" >
                    <apex:outputPanel >

                         <apex:dataTable id="dt2c" styleClass="allPDFdatatables" headerClass="allPDFdatacols" columnClasses="allPDFdatacols" rowClasses="allPDFdatarows" value="{!PriorYRcontractSectionList}" var="pyr" rules="all" cellpadding="5"  >
                            <apex:column value="{!pyr.Name}" headerValue="Contracts"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!pyr.ULTIMATE_PREMIUM__c}" headerValue="Ult Prem"/>                                                       
                            <apex:column value="{!pyr.PAID_LOSS__c}" headerValue="Ttl Rprd Loss" rendered="{! (allNulls_PAID_LOSS_dt2c || hidecols) }"/>  
                             <apex:column value="{!pyr.ACR__c}" headerValue="Ttl ACR"  rendered="{! (allNulls_ACR_dt2c || hidecols) }" />  
                            <apex:column value="{!pyr.ULTIMATE_LOSS__c}" headerValue="Ttl Ult Loss Incl ACR" rendered="{! (allNulls_ULTIMATE_LOSS_dt2c || hidecols) }" />                               
                            <apex:column value="{!pyr.Ultimate_Loss_Ratio__c}" headerValue="Ult LR%" rendered="{! (allNulls_Ultimate_Loss_Ratio_dt2c || hidecols) }" />  
                            <apex:column value="{!pyr.F_DETAIL_COMMISSION__c}" headerValue="Ult Comm%" rendered="{! (allNulls_F_DETAIL_COMMISSION_dt2c || hidecols) }" />  
                            <apex:column value="{!pyr.F_DETAIL_BROKERAGE__c}" headerValue="Ult Brok%" rendered="{! (allNulls_F_DETAIL_BROKERAGE_dt2c || hidecols) }" />     
                            <apex:column value="{!pyr.ULT_OVERHEAD_EXCL_CATS__c}" headerValue="Ult OH%" rendered="{! (allNulls_ULT_OVERHEAD_EXCL_CATS_dt2c || hidecols) }" />
                            <apex:column value="{!pyr.ULT_CR_ACCT_OH__c}" headerValue="Ult CR%" rendered="{! (allNulls_ULT_CR_ACCT_OH_dt2c || hidecols) }" /> 
                            <apex:column value="{!pyr.ULT_CR_ACCT_EXCL_OH__c}" headerValue="Ult CR x OH%" rendered="{! (allNulls_ULT_CR_ACCT_EXCL_OH_dt2c || hidecols) }" />                               
                            <apex:column value="{!pyr.ITD_CR_EXCL_ACCT_OH__c}" headerValue="ITD CR x OH%" rendered="{! (allNulls_ITD_CR_EXCL_ACCT_OH_dt2c || hidecols) }" />                                                                
                        </apex:dataTable>

                   </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionstatus>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

```
.allPDFdatatables {
text-align: right;
font-family: 'Arial'; 
font-size: 75%;   
vertical-align: middle;
border-collapse: collapse; 
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
color: blue;
-fs-table-paginate: paginate;
border-spacing: 0;
cellspacing 0;}

.allPDFdatarows {
text-align: right;
font-family: 'Arial'; 
font-size: 75%;   
vertical-align: middle;
border-collapse: collapse; 
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
color: black;    
cellspacing 0;}

.allPDFdatacols {
border-collapse: collapse; 
border: 1px solid black;
cellspacing 0;   }

@page {size: ledger landscape;
@bottom-right { content: "Page " counter(page) "of " counter(pages);}
margin-top:3cm; margin-left:2.54cm; margin-right:2.54cm; margin-bottom:3cm; margin-top:1cm;  margin-left:1cm; margin-right:1cm; margin-bottom:1cm; }
```

Comment: Looks like padding issue across table, try removing `cellpadding="5"` in `datatable` as well as `padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;` in `allPDFdatatables` class style. Also remove any spacing.

Comment: Excellent. Shut down the cell padding. Tables looking much better now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table has some default borders and you have following padding or spacing in your code:

- try removing `cellpadding="5"` in *datatable* as well as `padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;` in *allPDFdatatables* class style. Also remove any spacing